# Fastest way to return a list of records depending on many many-to-many relationships

Tags: design, api, api-design, sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing an API in Rails and the following requirement is established (it's really more complicated, but I want put a simple example):

1. There are `users` and `messages`.
2. `users` have a gender (`gender_id`), belong to a country (`country_id`) and also have a civil status (`civil_status_id`).
3. When a message is created, these can be targeted to several `users` depending on its attributes (i.e. multiple countries, multiple civil statuses and one gender), but a message can also be global and this means that it should be addressed to all users (this is determined with a `boolean` attribute called `global` in every message record).
4. I am also asked to allow exceptions if a message is declared as global, this means that the `admin` in the app should be able to create a "global", including all countries with the exception of Russia and China and also excluding widowed users.
5. Each user has an inbox of up to 20 messages.

## What is my solution for this?

To fulfill this requirement, I thought about doing the following, but I have many doubts, above all I am interested in not having a lot of load in the application every time the user wants to see his messages, because in the first place there are hundreds of countries, multiple civil statuses and the number of users can be from tens to tens of thousands or even more. So any criticism or improvement is welcome.

1. In the app the `User` and `Message` models currently exist, but the issue with the messages was handled poorly, for example when creating a message the administrator could only choose one country, one civil status, one gender (this should remains the same because there are only two genders in the app, so chosing male and female would be a synonimous to global). In other words the users table had a `country_id`, `civil_status_id`, `gender_id`and you received a message if this message was global or there was a match between your and the message's `country_id`, `gender_id` or `civil_status`.

This was made with the following code:

```
Message.all.where("global = ? OR civil_status_id = ? OR country_id = ?  OR gender_id = ?", true, user.civil_status_id, user.country_id, user.gender_id).limit(20)
```

Where `user` was the `current_user`.

2. To cover points 3 and 4 (messages targeted to users from several countries, civil statuses, etc. and global messages with exceptions) I was thinking about the following:

   2.1 Create the join tables `civil_statuses_messages` and `countries_messages` while `gender_id` remain in the `users` table.

   2.2 Then when a message is creted the join tables `civil_statuses_messages` and `countries_messages` should be populated according to the target population declared by the administrator.

   2.3 Finally when someone wants to see the inbox, the action associated with the return of the messages that the user should see should create an array and go through the last created messages, one by one. Then if a message is set to global all the associations with countries, gender or civil statuses should be considered as exclusions, and thus the message should be discarded if the user is, for example, from one of the countries in `message.countries` (where message is the current message within the iteration).

   In the other hand, if a message is not set to global then all the associations with countries, gender or civil statuses should be considered as inclusions, and thus the message should be pushed in the array if the user is, for example, from one of the countries in `message.countries` (where message is the current message within the iteration).

   When the array reach a size of 20 it should be returned in JSON and that's it.

**The problems that I see**

1. For example, if there are 20 thousand messages in the system, but only 5 messages are addressed to people in the Yemen country, when a person from that country wants to see their inbox, then the system would scroll through 20 thousand messages, as it would not reach the 20 messages. So this solution is poor when a message is addressed to a very very small audience.

What recommendations do you propose?

I do not think that this application will have more than hundreds or thousands of users or more than several dozens or hundreds of messages (being realistic), but I do not want to be limited if many and many people download and use the app and I put several adminis.

Answer (score 1):

**Test it and find out**.

Create a Messages table and write a short program to fill it up with random data.  Since you consider 20,000 rows a lot, put in 500,000 rows.

Run your queries and time them.  If any come back slower than you can blink, put in the appropriate [indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2955459/427192) and time them again.

Finding 5 records out of 500,000 that have a particular value is child's play on a modern database provided the index has been set up.